# c# wpf DataGrid: programmatically changing image source on bound columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a SQL Database with computers names bound to a DataGrid Like This:

```
                <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:FileIconConverter2 x:Key="FileIconConverter2"/>
                <BitmapImage x:Key="Image-Unknown" UriSource="../Images/Status-Unknown.ico" />
                <BitmapImage x:Key="Image-Good" UriSource="../Images/Status-Good.ico" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource Image-Unknown}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date d m yyyy" Binding="{Binding 'Date d m yyyy'}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Device Name" Binding="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="OS" Binding="{Binding OS}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="OS" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EOL" Binding="{Binding DeviceAge}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Binding="{Binding IP}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MAC" Binding="{Binding Mac}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

What I am trying to do is when you click on a row, have the status column image update to show if the computer is online by changing the image.
The Status column is not in the database. 
whenever I try changing the content of the status column I get [icon] or [bitmap] text, not an image, and if I scroll down then back up the image defaults back.

Here is the 
Any Suggestions?

Edit:
Where the table can contain 100's of entries, I only want to check the online status when a row is selected. So I'm trying to use SelectionChanged event on datagrid1 like this:

```
    private void datagrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
        DataGridCell rowColumn = dataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
        string CellValue = ((TextBlock)rowColumn.Content).Text;
        log.Warn(CellValue);

        //myclass.GetCell(datagrid1, row.GetIndex(), 0).Content = Properties.Resources.Status_Good;
        myclass.GetCell(datagrid1, row.GetIndex(), 0).Content = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@".\Images\Status-good.ico");

    }
```

The myClass.GetCell code comes from this [post.](http://techiethings.blogspot.ca/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html)

But, as you can see in this screen shot, I only get text and not the image.
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXD0M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add triggers to your image ?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image >
               <Image.Style>
                   <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource Image-Unknown}"/>
                   <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourModelPropertyStatus}" Value="true">
                          <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource Image-Good}"/>
                     </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Image.Style>
            </Image> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Edit :**

*Solution 1 (the closest to your existing code)*

Rather than searching and editing the cell content in code behind (which is really bad practice), use the arguments given by the selectionChanged callback like `e.AddedItems` and `e.RemovedItems` wich will give you the business models (representing your devices) wich have been added and removed. Something like

```
        foreach (var addedItem in e.AddedItems)
        {
            var device = (Device) addedItem;
            device.CheckStatus();
        }
        foreach (var remItem in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            var device = (Device)remItem;
            device.SetToUnknown();
        }
```

Where `CheckStatus` is the method that check the online status and will set the flag `YourModelPropertyStatus` to true of false (and thus active the triggers described above)

*Solution 2 (the cleanest way)*

The best and cleanest way to acheive what you want, keeping the triggers solution in the XAML, is to manage everything on your view model using a `CollectionView` to wrapp your devices collection.
In your XAML DataGrid set the `IsSynchronizedToCurrentItem=true` and then, in your view model, subscribe to `CurrentChanged` event and in the callback get the CurrentItem of the `CollectionView` and call the `CheckStatus();` that can be either in your view model or in your device object.

Comment: I think this would update all rows at once, I'm only looking to change the Status as a user selects a row. I updated the original post to show my datagrid1_SelectionChanged